# Jquery three datepickers together

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I created 2 datepicker input fields on the left side, first is **From** date and the second is **TO** date and I also created a div with class `datepicker` that displays datepicker calendar on the right side so for the first two input fields I use this

```
$(function() {
  $('#datepickerSickFrom').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $('#dateTo').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
    }
  });

  $('#datepickerSickTo').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $('#dateFrom').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
    }
  });
});
```

And now I want these two inputs to be connected into the third datepicker div that I created, how am I suppose to do that?

This is my HTML

```
<div class="group">
  <p class="inputIcon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
  <input type="text" class="setLabel datepicker" placeholder="11/30/2017" id="datepickerSickFrom">
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="position: absolute;right: 0;top: 17px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <p class="inputIcon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
  <input type="text" class="setLabel datepicker" placeholder="11/30/2017" id="datepickerSickTo">
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="position: absolute;right: 0;top: 17px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="datepicker" id="sickPanelDatepicker"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "connected to the third datepicker" ? What kind of connection?

Comment: @Vivek so when the user selects the FROM date and then selects the TO date it should show the selectet range into the third calendar that i display  into the div

Comment: I see references to 4 datepickers not 2

Comment: Can you post your html also?

Comment: @Vivek i posted the html

Comment: As @charlietfl said, there's no input with id `dateFrom`

Comment: What do you mean by 'connected' also where is "#dateTo", "#dateForm"?

Comment: @SergeK. it was just an example, you can see my code and see what i want to do

Comment: Nobody can *"see what you want to do"* without a proper explanation of what it is along with clarifying why there are already 4 datepickers referenced

Comment: @charlietfl the first input has id="datepickerSickFrom" it should take the first date, and the second input has id="datepickerSickTo" it should take the second date and in the third div where i have the id="sickPanelDatepicker" it should draw the range that is given on the first two inputs, do you understand me now

Comment: Sure...and why are references to 2 other datepickers `dateTo` and `dateFrom` shown? And why can't you do the same as what those references are doing?

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you intend to do.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#datepickerSickFrom').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $('#sickPanelDatepicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
    }
  });
  $('#datepickerSickTo').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $('#sickPanelDatepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
    }
  });
  $('#sickPanelDatepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="group">
  <p class="inputIcon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
  <input type="text" class="setLabel datepicker" placeholder="11/30/2017" id="datepickerSickFrom">
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="position: absolute;right: 0;top: 17px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <p class="inputIcon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
  <input type="text" class="setLabel datepicker" placeholder="11/30/2017" id="datepickerSickTo">
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="position: absolute;right: 0;top: 17px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="datepicker" id="sickPanelDatepicker"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this should also work if i change the from and to date from the **sickPanelDatepicker**